# Full-table SELECT of mysql table via pandas dataframe greater than the sum of its parts

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

```
users_old = pd.read_sql('SELECT {} FROM ResUsers WHERE PERMISSION=1 \
               AND DateAdded<"2013-01-01"'.format(RU_fields), db)

users_2013 = pd.read_sql('SELECT {} FROM ResUsers WHERE PERMISSION=1 \
               DateAdded>"2013-01-01" AND DateAdded<"2014-01-01"'.format(RU_fields), db)

users_2014 = pd.read_sql('SELECT {} FROM ResUsers WHERE PERMISSION=1 \
               DateAdded>"2014-01-01"'.format(RU_fields), db)
```

When I run these three queries in ipython, the process ends up using about 16.5GB of memory. However, when I run this query:

```
users = pd.read_sql('SELECT {} FROM ResUsers WHERE PERMISSION=1'.format(RU_fields), db)
```

The ipython process uses more and more memory until the it crashes. The machine I'm using has 60GB RAM total.

Now, Permission and DateAdded are non-null, so I do't know what could be going on here. For sanity check, I tried:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ResUsers WHERE Permission=1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 31577307 |
+----------+
1 row in set (8.39 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ResUsers WHERE Permission=1 AND DateAdded<"2013-01-01"
    -> ;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  8255583 |
+----------+
1 row in set (51.13 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ResUsers WHERE Permission=1 AND DateAdded>"2013-01-01" AND DateAdded<"2014-01-01";
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 11966819 |
+----------+
1 row in set (55.76 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM ResUsers WHERE Permission=1 AND DateAdded>"2014-01-01";
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 11354972 |
+----------+
1 row in set (51.11 sec)
```

Which didn't really restore sanity, as 8255583+11966819+11354972 = 31577374 != 31577307, although it is pretty close...is there a reason counts in mysql might be off by a tiny amount?

What's going on, or at least, how could go about debugging this? If maybe there were some way to figure out what was going on in memory as this call was happening I could figure it out?

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: looks like you are losing records created on 2013-01-01 and 2014-01-01. One of you operators should be >= or <=

Comment: Yes, I would have fixed those queries if 31577374 were less than 31577307, but in fact it is 67 more!

Comment: whoops... I didn't do the math, I just saw the operators.